# Can't get map to appear in Python Data Visualization

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization, mapbox

I am trying to visualize US COVID-19 data geographically within Python. Currently I have a CSV with all my data imported which contains case numbers, longitudes, latitudes etc. Currently my code is as follows:

```
df=pd.read_csv
fig=px.scatter_mapbox(df,lat='Lat', lon='Long', hover_name='Province_State', size='Confirmed',mapbox_style='open-streetmap',template='plotly_dark')
fig.write_html("Time_series_county_JH.html")

fig.show()
```

However, when I run the code I just get a black box with the legend on the right

Would be great if someone can help on how I can get the actual map to appear rather than just a black output. I am very new to Python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide the sample data for us to recreate the issue.

Comment: Are you using the jupyterlab as an IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing a problem with rendering the image using plotly.

You could set the renderers for the plotly image as below:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "colab"
```

And change the following line in your code as shown below:

```
pio.show(fig)
```

If the figure still shows black, then it is the problem with `mapbox_style`. Change it to the relevant requirement.

```
mapbox_style='carto-darkmatter'
```

As a whole:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/content/COVID-19_Cases_US.csv")
fig=px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat='Lat', lon='Long_', hover_name='Province_State', size='Confirmed',color='Confirmed',mapbox_style='carto-darkmatter',template='plotly_dark',zoom=0, size_max=70)

fig.write_html("Time_series_county_JH.html")

pio.show()
```

Result:

[image: resultant image]

### Update:

for `mapbox_style` = 'open-street-map' and code:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/content/COVID-19_Cases_US.csv")

fig=px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat='Lat', lon='Long_', hover_name='Province_State', size='Confirmed',color='Confirmed',mapbox_style='open-street-map',template='plotly_dark',zoom=4, size_max=70)

fig.write_html("Time_series_county_JH.html")

fig.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Roxy, I have tried implementing the above code but I am receiving an error saying 'localhost refused to connect.'. I am working in a colab document found here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KGqzbEeUEXhI3JnJJP64CLEaR6znE69w?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah I see! Then I have updated the solution for you. ;)

Comment: Given it another try however unfortunately I am back to the same problem again :( just a black box with the legend to the right...

Comment: Still no luck... are you able to access the colab link and does the visualization work using the above code for you?

Comment: Not able to do so.. Yes I am working on it. Tries different renederers. :/

Comment: Maybe this link works: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KGqzbEeUEXhI3JnJJP64CLEaR6znE69w?usp=sharing

Comment: Really appreciate the help btw

Comment: are you missing on your tokens? maybe? the map_access_token is not set

Comment: Found it. It is the problem with the 'mapbox_style'. I have updated the solution above.

Comment: Here is the link to the colab file: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KGqzbEeUEXhI3JnJJP64CLEaR6znE69w?usp=sharing#scrollTo=ZdQj7gDqHVGg

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much Roxy for your help - super appreciated!!! :)

Comment: Could you accept and upvote the answer. It would be quite helpful. :)